# Python script than run another python script, ffmpeg2vmaf

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, ffmpeg, netflix

I want to build a little API to use ffmpeg2vmaf to analyze videos that are made for the video streaming (DASH, HLS).

I'm on Linux Ubuntu 16.04, I'm using python 3.

My API can now concatenate the files into an MP4 file. To do it I'm using the library `subprocess` and the command `cat`.

But when I want to use ffmpeg2vmaf it can't find a library that ffmpeg2vmaf use.

This is how I do:

```
try:
    os.chdir("/home/USERNAME/VMAF/vmaf/")
    output_cmd = subprocess.check_output(["sudo ./ffmpeg2vmaf WIDTH HEIGHT \
                 '/home/alexis/video/ref.mp4' '/home/alexis/video/dist.mp4'\
                 >> '/home/alexis/analyze/analyze.txt'"], shell = True)
except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
    print("Error")
```

The error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "./ffmpeg2vmaf", line 8, in <module>
        from vmaf.config import VmafConfig, DisplayConfig
ImportError: No module named vmaf.config
```

But if I use the same command without python, in the terminal, it works.

I have try to put my API in the same folder as "ffmpeg2vmaf" but it still doesn't work.

Thank you by advance

Comment: Do you have a `__init__.py` file in the vmaf module folder?

Comment: Check that your `PYTHONPATH` environment variable includes the directory where `vmaf.config` resides.

Comment: There is no `__init.py__` in this module.

Comment: I have added the path to `vmaf.config` but it still can't find it.